# Visual Studio 2013 : how to find out who has what checked out

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am using VS 2013 and trying to find out in a given TFS folder who has what checked out and google search results are not helping. Under find menu, I don't see any option that would help in finding out this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TFS Power Tools provide enhancements to the Source Control Explorer (as well as many other things), which will allow you to search for files by Status, i.e. Check Out.

The 2013 TFS Power Tools are available from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f

Info in the download page explains:

> This tool provides additional Visual Studio menu options and
>   functions to support finding files under version control by status or
>   wildcard, opening a folder using File Explorer from the Source Control
>   Explorer context menu...

Comment: Paul, you are a life savor. Thank you very much x10

Comment: Installing the power tools addin corrupted my VS 2013 installation.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Source Control -> Find in Source Control -> Status -> "Your settings" -> Find.

Comment: I don't see the above option

Comment: I don't see the following option " Find in Source Control "

Answer (score 0):

If you're a TFS administrator you may also want to add [TFS sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to your toolset. Its great for finding out the status of files or workspace information (the tree view filter is nicer to work with IMO) but then you've also the control to be able to do something about it!